# Order posts randomly, not by date

Tags: php, sort

I'd like to know how to order by "random" instead of by "date".

Can someone help me modify this so it gets posts randomly instead of by date?

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&orderby=date&fields=all&tag='.$tag);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$randomPosts = get_posts(array(
   'orderby' => 'rand',
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
   'tag' => $tag,
));
```

Take a gander at the [`WP_Query` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) uses `WP_Query` under the hood, so you can use any arguments that may be used there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rand as orderby 
 check below code

```
 $args = array(
         'posts_per_page'   => 5,
         'offset'           => 0,
         'category'         => '',
         'category_name'    => '',
         'orderby'          => 'post_date',
         'order'            => 'rand',
         'include'          => '',
         'exclude'          => '',
         'meta_key'         => '',
         'meta_value'       => '',
         'post_type'        => 'post',
         'post_mime_type'   => '',
         'post_parent'      => '',
         'post_status'      => 'publish',
         'suppress_filters' => true 
); 

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<li><h2>Random Post</h2>
<ul>
<?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=5'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</li>
```

You can customize the styling around it. If you want to display more than 5 posts, simply change the number 5 to the number of your choice.